# How to test for number smaller than other number

Tags: shell-script, scripting, date, timestamps

I have a script that goes like this:

```
while :
do
   Start_Time=$(date +"%s")

      MAIN PROGRAM GOES HERE (CROPPED TO SHORTEN THINGS)

   Run_Time=$(( $(date +"%s") - $Start_Time ))

   if [[ $Run_Time < $Wait_Time ]]
   then
      Delay_Time=$(( $Wait_Time - $Run_Time ))
      sleep $Delay_Time
   else
      echo "Delay exceeded" 
      echo $Run_Time
      echo $Wait_Time
   fi
done
```

And my problem is that sometimes even if the run time is smaller than the wait time it fails the <  test

Here is an output from the last run:

```
Delay exceeded
Run_Time 4
Wait_Time 30
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try running this code snippet:

```
if [[ 5 < 20 ]]
then
    echo "5 < 20, as expected"
else
    echo "5 is not less than 20, but why?"
fi
```

And the output would be `5 is not less than 20, but why?`.  The answer is that you're using the `<` conditional expression operator, which is documented as doing:

```
       string1 < string2
              True if string1 sorts before string2 lexicographically in the current locale.
```

And your problem is that "20" is lexicographically (or, basically, alphabetically) before "5".

You're looking for:

```
if (( $Run_Time < $Wait_Time ))
```

instead - this uses arithmetic evaluation and an arithmetic less-than, which is what you need.

Comment: +1 You can also use `-lt` in place of `<`; the former is specifically for integer comparison so can be used inside `[]`.

Comment: @goldilocks your documentation on operators seems really complete, do you have a link? I really need to brush up on those. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Thank you very much goldilock. BTW to anyone else that may land here for a similar problem, I also encountered a similar "read the manual or you wont know about it" behavior using -eq as an operator. -eq can lead to unexpected results when you are testing if a variable is equal to 0 ie.: [[ $var -eq 0 ]] it will still test true if $var is unset. You can use = or == instead which behaves properly. There is a LOT to learn about linux... im loving it.